# How to break one table row into multiple lines in RMD

Tags: r, r-markdown

```
summary <- summary(data)
knitr::kable(summary)
```

I have the following code in RMD. However, there are more than 20 attributes in the dataset, so that the width of the table generated by summary() is too larger to show the entire table in a row in the page.

Just wondering how could I do to adjust the summary() table?

Comment: (1) research how to rotate at least one page to landscape; (2) research how to change font sizes (if it's really close); (3) choose your attributes, perhaps most-relevant first; or (4) break your table into two or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans) answer, maybe there is another way of reducing the table width :

1- **In a table :** you should consider transposing the columns into lines. The 6 statistics of summary() should be the columns, and the variables (attributes, according to you) should be the line, e.g.,

```
summary <- t(summary(data)) # just a basic version, for clarity.
```

2- **In a graphic :** if you want all of your attributes renders like columns, maybe you should consider some boxplot (or geom_col and geom_errorbar), with facets or by using an x axis-values for each attribute ?  With facet_grid() or facet_wrap(), it's more easy to compare a bunch of attributes than in a big table. If your want to compare things, fix the scales between the facets. If necessary, you can use the grid package, in order to define each facet size and aspect...

Excellent day